# Post URL Not Showing After Index Only Home Page Showing on Google

Tags: indexing, google-search-console

Google search shows my website's home page url in search results instead of individual blog posts. My post is on the first or second page but Google shows only the home page url on that specific keyword, Why?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0FoS.png)

I want to solve this issue. So please help me.